# ViewPager infinite scrolling in one direction

Tags: java, android

So, this is a dumb question, I know.

What I want to do is a ViewPager where you can scroll into one direction, it then loads a page with random content (it's always the same layout, though). It keeps the last page open so if you scroll left, you get the page you just saw, but only that page, not the page before that page, if you understand.

Last page - current page - next page.

Not more, and to the right it should be infinite, it's loading the content from a database. I've found codes for dynamic ViewPager but I can't get them to work. Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276846/one-side-viewpager-swiping-only

Comment: Well, that's kind of but not really what I'm looking for. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The basic trick is to write a custom adapter that always reports three items, but manages which three are the previous, current, and next.

Comment: Okay, well, thank you. I have a really hard time understanding how this particular function works.